# How to count the Index of an instance?

Tags: python, oop, server, constructor, instance

I want to start multiple servers like this:

```
Server 1
Server 2
Server 3
```

I have already written a code:

```
class Server:
     def __init__(self, index):
          self.index = index
```

My main is looking like this:

```
server1 = Server(1)
server1.run()
```

So my question is as you can read in the captio:
How can I global count the Index of different instances (Servers) dynamically?

Comment: What do you mean by "count"? You can store every index you specify in a list, if that's what you're after.

Comment: `servers = [Server(i) for i in range(1, 4)]`?

Comment: I mean with count that dynamically it counts a variable up, when i start a new serve (new .py file is execute here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the total instance count in a class variable.

```
class Server:
    instances = 0   
    def __init__(self):
         Server.instances += 1
         self.index = Server.instances
```

Solving this problem across multiple instances requires more work.  You must use a file to hold the counter, and you must ensure that two processes don't fight over who gets to open the file next.  This should work on Linux:

```
import fcntl
class Server:
    CNTR = 'mycounter.txt'
    def __init__(self):
        if not os.path.exists(CNTR):
            open(CNTR,'w').write('0')
        fctl.lock( f, fcntl.LOCK_EX )
        n = int(open(CNTR).read()) + 1
        open(CNTR,'w').write(str(n))
        fctl.lock( f, fcntl.LOCK_UN )

        self.index = n
```

Comment: Thanks! And how could I implement it, when I want to start the servers from different .py files?

Comment: That doesn't change anything.  Any time you create a `Server` instance, it will get an instance number.  Remember, when you do `import Server from myfile`, it's still the same class object.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! I dont import the server nowhere. I just want to start for example 3 times the server file in three different consoles. And then I want to increase the counter by 1 for each Server.

Comment: Hang on, that's a VERY different question from the one you asked.  If you want the number to be retained across different PROCESSES, then your only choice is to store the number in a file.  Open, read, increment, write.  You obviously can't keep anything in memory, since they do not share any memory.

Comment: I know its another question than I asked. I only asked that for interest. Thanks, for the answer!